# how to set password to micro SD card programmatically?

Tags: passwords, password-protection, copy-protection, password-encryption, data-protection

is there any way to write protect micro sd card with password through programming (Java/C)?

primarily I wanted to set a password to micro sd card and the sd card should have access only if we provide the password.

I come to know that nokia mobile phones were doing this before, hope there is some way of doing this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the phones just encrypt the data (not technically lock it) and only they know how to unencrypted it. The closest that you could get to protecting the micro sd card would be to encrypt whatever you want to write on it. Hope this at least gave you an idea of how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Phones use the CID number (card ID number written in ROM) of the SD or microSD card to encrypt the data and act as a key.  So Lonnez is right, you need to encrypt the data, not write protect it.  The other part of this, is having a device which can read the CID number and spit it out.  Nexcopy.com has one for bulk use (manufacturing) but I suspect you would like a single card reader solution, not bulk.

You should also contact the SDCard Association as they could help you out with a more specific answer reg the ability to wp SD media.  sdcard.org